# Redis returning 'None' as result

Tags: python, redis

I'm building a scraping app that shall go through multiple pages, scrape and return results from those pages. I enqueue tasks using Redis. I bumped into an issue with the results. When I run a script and scrape the data only from one page, redis successfully stores the result for 500 seconds, default, and I'm able to retrieve them under job_id. However, when I try to scrape multiple pages, redis returns None as result. The resulting data get printed normally by the function before returning it. I'm posting the code below, perhaps you now why this happens:

```
contacts = []

def flatten(list):
flattened = []
for i in list:
    for z in i:
        flattened.append(z)
return flattened

def start(url, cookie=True):
if cookie == True:
    load_cookie(driver)
driver.get(url)
start_scroll(driver)
#checking if the page has contacts
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("some xml")
if len(elements) > 0:
    profiles = get_data(driver)
    contacts.append(profiles)
    next_page_url = next_url(driver)
    print(profiles)
    start(next_page_url, False)
else:
    print('returenter code herening contacts')
    flattened = flatten(contacts)
    print(flattened)
    return flattened
```